# mod_wsgi: Exception occurred processing WSGI script (django deployment)

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to deploy a django project with the following Apache configuration:

**Apache virtualhost configuration**

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/project/backend
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    WSGIDaemonProcess backend python-home=/var/www/project/myenv python-path=/var/www/gestor_documental/backend

    WSGIProcessGroup backend
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/project/backend/backend/wsgi.py process-group=backend
    Alias /static/ /var/www/project/backend/static/

    <Directory /var/www/project/backend>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
</Virtualhost>
```

**wsgi.load file**

```
LoadModule wsgi_module "/var/www/project/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py35.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"
WSGIPythonHome "/var/www/project/myenv"
```

The wsgi.py is the one django brings by default

**wsgi.py**

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "backend.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**This is the project tree:**

```
project
|- backend
|  |- api (django app)
|  |- backend
|     |- ...
|     |- settings.py
|     |- wsgi.py
|-- myenv (virtualenv)
```

**And this is the error log I keep getting when i try to load the web:**

```
mod_wsgi (pid=38953): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/project/backend/backend/wsgi.py'.
mod_wsgi (pid=38953): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/project/backend/backend/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/var/www/project/backend/backend/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
  application = get_wsgi_application()
 File "/var/www/project/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
  django.setup(set_prefix=False)
 File "/var/www/project/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 22, in setup
  configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
 File "/var/www/project/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
  self._setup(name)
 File "/var/www/project/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
  self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
 File "/var/www/project/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 97, in __init__
  mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
 File "/var/www/project/myenv/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'backend'
```

I've followed every single tutorial and try tons of configurations but still getting the same error.

I'm using **python 3.5.2** in a virtualenv and **Apache 2.4.18**

I've installed mod_wsgi via pip3.

Could someone help me with this and tell me what am i doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Are importing `backend` somewhere in your files? Is backend only a folder or also a file? Because you're trying to import the module `backend` somewhere and it cannot find a module that's called `backend`.

Comment: That's the weird thing. `backend` is the name of my project's folder and i didn't import it anywhere

Comment: You also didn't import it like that in your `wsgi.py`?

Comment: The `wsgi.py` is the one django brings by default. I actually don't know what that file does. I'm going to edit the post and put the file so you can see what it has inside.

Comment: What os the full path of the Django settings file, ie., path ending in ``backend/settings.py``? The ``python-path`` should include the parent directory of that ``backend`` directory in that path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved it changing the `wsgi.py` file adding the next lines:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('/var/www/project/backend')
```

I don't know if this is the correct answer but it actually worked with this workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Its this line in the `wsgi.py`:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "backend.settings")
```

There's no `backend.settings` in `project/backend/backend`.
It's trying to find a third backend folder, so remove `backend` from that line.

Comment: You are right the problem was it didn't find the `backend` but if remove that it said the same but just with `settings`. I posted the solution that worked for me in case other noobs are as lost as me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem :) glad I was able to help